# Injecting @Stateless EJB in Arquillian tests

Tags: jboss-arquillian

A weird problem when running Arquillian test. If I try to use an EJB annotated with @Stateless, I get this error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [MyEjbRemote] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private com.org.app.ejb.InjectionTest.ejb]
```

I have the following test class + deployment for the Arquillian:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class InjectionTest extends TestCase {

  @Inject
  private MyEjbRemote ejb;

  @Deployment
  public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar").addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml"));
    jar.addClass(MyEjbRemote.class);
    jar.addClass(MyEjb.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void checkInjection() {
    TestCase.assertNotNull(ejb);
  }
}
```

The EJB looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Default
public class MyEjb implements MyEjbRemote {
  public MyEjb() {
  }
}
```

The remote interface just has @Remote annotation.

If I change the **@Stateless** to **@Named**, it works. But I wan to use the @Stateless.

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.9.Final</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I had this issue, when using the Weld-EE dependency. Try using Weld-SE

Comment: @Albert Bos I have to keep this in mind if I need to work on this again. My solution was to create overriding EJB just for test where it uses different annotation than in live server.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test injection of Stateless EJBs that are not Singletons you need to deploy to an embedded container.

I had the same issue and this blog post pointed me in the right direction.
https://blog.payara.fish/how-to-test-applications-with-payara-server-micro-with-arquillian

My working pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>payara-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.2020.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have to give +1 just for answering this question after almost 5 years after it was posted. :) Can't check anymore from the original project if this would be the right solution, but I trust it would work. Cheers.